# htaccess condition that adds www. to the url only if it doesn't already contain a string in the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site: example.com.

I have a development site: development.example.com

I have been asked to prepend the 'www.' to the url but I can't add it to the development site.

Is there a way to get the condition to check that the site doesn't have 'www.' and doesn't contain the string 'development.' and if this is the case, add the 'www.' string to the url?

Here is my current:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

My logic a bit explained: if I run the https redirect first I can ensure the url for both 'www.' and 'development.' are moved to https.
I then wish to edit the '!^www.' condition in the second part to add the 'www.' if there is no 'www.' & no 'development.'.

But this current rule OBVIOUSLY changes the url of my development site to https://www.development.example.com causing an issue.

Would the answer be something similar to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..!^development\. [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I have managed to chain two RewriteCond together is like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^development\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

After reading up a little further - you can just chain your conditions before the RewriteRule.